# (Android Studio) Why are buttons added through XML different than those added through java. How can i make them constant

Tags: java, android

When I add a button with XML is uses a different style compared to adding one through Java. I have looked into how the styles and themes in android studio work but I cant seem to figure it out. Everything up to the purple delete button is XML. I wanted to make a copy of it in Java so I can easily make duplicates.

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_Notifications"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".NotificationsActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_notifications"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_plot_route"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/def_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/plot_route"/>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <!-- Column left to right -->
            <!-- Row up and down -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/def_margin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="222222222222222"
                android:layout_gravity=""/>
            <TableRow>
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/def_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="3"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/def_margin"
                    android:text="@string/enable"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/def_margin"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```
        // Make table
        TableLayout newTable = new TableLayout(this);
        // Add title
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        title.setText(name);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        newTable.addView(title);
        // Params
        TableRow.LayoutParams trParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        // Date
        EditText newEditText = new EditText(this);
        newEditText.setText(date);
        trParams.weight = 3;
        newRow.addView(newEditText,trParams);
        // Enable
        trParams.weight =1;
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setText("Enable");
        newRow.addView(checkBox, trParams);
        newTable.addView(newRow);

        Button del = new Button(this);
        del.setText("Delete");
        del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        newTable.addView(del);
        llMain.addView(newTable);

        llMain.invalidate();
```

Comment: Which button is added by code and which is added by XML? Can you show us the code and XML file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to have the same style then you can use `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_layout_id)`
instead of `new Button(this)` and you need to extract the button to a independent xml layout file